# How to add a text box and show data on Veins Qtenv?

Tags: qt, omnet++, veins

I am using Veins to do some Mobile Edge Computing simulations. To improve the visual effect, I am trying to show real time data of some nodes. For example, my application will return the communication delay in real time. In the Qtenv of Veins, I want to show the delay values in a text box just above the node icon. How to realize that? Or in which documentation can I get some help? Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a node's Display String (specifically, its `t` tag) should do exactly that. See https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:display-strings for the full documentation.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly the answer. I used to regard display strings as the setting of the figure and ignored 't' tag...

Comment: Sorry to bother you again... Currently I want to slightly change the font size but I don't find any parameter that I could change. I find cLabelFigure but I don't know where the 't' tag part is realized so I can't modify it. Do you know how to set the font size? Thank you!